# Matplotlib histogram is adding a small bar at the second histogram bin

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, histogram

I think may hist function have some problems, at certain cases when I plot an histogram with matplotlib:

```
pylab.figure()
H, bins, _  = pylab.hist([2,2])
print H
print bins
```

The result is:

[image: histogram]

```
[ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  2.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
[ 1.5  1.6  1.7  1.8  1.9  2.   2.1  2.2  2.3  2.4  2.5]
```

Do you see at the plot that "bump" at between 1.5 and 1.6, where it is coming from? How can I avoid it?

Comment: what is the return if you write ``np.sum((ar < 2))``?

Comment: Can you edit the array or at least as much of the array into the question so that it still shows this "bump" at 0? Try to make it as small as possible though. :)

Comment: your bin left edge contains -0.5 maybe you can alter the align option for pylab.hist and get rid of the -0.5   align : ['left' | 'mid' | 'right']

Comment: @Mseifert I just simplified the question to a minimal expression that shows the problem.

Comment: @DanPatterson Thanks! That's a good advice :)

Answer (score 0):

This is interesting.

You can look at the rectangles generated:

```
ax = plt.subplot(111)
h, bins, rects = ax.hist([2, 2])

for r in rects:
    print(r.get_bbox())

# Bbox(x0=1.5, y0=0.0, x1=1.6, y1=0.0)
# Bbox(x0=1.6, y0=0.0, x1=1.7, y1=0.0)
# Bbox(x0=1.7, y0=0.0, x1=1.8, y1=0.0)
# Bbox(x0=1.8000000000000003, y0=0.0, x1=1.9000000000000001, y1=0.0)
# Bbox(x0=1.9, y0=0.0, x1=2.0, y1=0.0)
# Bbox(x0=1.9999999999999998, y0=0.0, x1=2.0999999999999996, y1=2.0)
# Bbox(x0=2.1000000000000005, y0=0.0, x1=2.2000000000000006, y1=0.0)
# Bbox(x0=2.2, y0=0.0, x1=2.3, y1=0.0)
# Bbox(x0=2.3, y0=0.0, x1=2.4, y1=0.0)
# Bbox(x0=2.4000000000000004, y0=0.0, x1=2.5000000000000004, y1=0.0)
```

Obviously, the histogram function generates a rectangle for each bin, even the empty ones. Although they have a height of 0, they are passed to the renderer and in some cases a spurious something is drawn.

I don't know how to prevent this. However, there is a solution, but it is rather hackish. The `hist` function puts a rectangular patch into the axis for each bin. It is possible to manually iterate over these patches and remove those with zero height:

```
ax = plt.subplot(111)
h, bins, rects = ax.hist([2, 2])

ax.patches = [p for p in ax.patches if p.get_height() > 0]
```

Comment: Yeah, so would I... Could probably be considered a bug in matplotlib if there is no good workaround.

Comment: Let's wait some days, and otherwise I will report it to matplotlit

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a rendering issue. Saving the figure to pdf does not show the glimpse. So, depending on your final use of the figure this might turn out to not be a problem.